# Unresolved Dependencies sbt with play framework

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt, sbt-plugin

As i am new to Stack Overflow please be patient i am working on a project with Play 2.5 exactly the starter example from the Website.

As i have to work with ebean i followed the Steps of Setting ebean in the plugins.sbt as like

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

and also in my build.sbt file

```
name := """play-java"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
libraryDependencies += cache
libraryDependencies += javaWs
libraryDependencies += filters
libraryDependencies += evolutions

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.webjars"               %% "webjars-play"       % "2.3.0",
  "org.webjars"               % "bootstrap"           % "3.0.0" exclude("org.webjars", "jquery"),
  "org.webjars"               % "jquery"              % "1.8.3"
)
```

but i get the following error output

```
 Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;3.0.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;3.0.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Dexter66\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.sbt\sbt-play-ebean\scala_2.11\sbt_0.13\3.0.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-play-ebean_2.11_0.13/3.0.0/sbt-play-ebean-3.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;3.0.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean:3.0.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean:3.0.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13) (C:\Users\Dexter66\Desktop\Uebungsprojekte_Play\play-java-starter-examp
le-2.5.x - Kopie\plugin.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- play-java:play-java_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info] Wrote C:\Users\Dexter66\Desktop\Uebungsprojekte_Play\play-java-starter-example-2.5.x - Kopie\target\scala-2.11\play-java_2.11-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;3.0.0: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1488)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1484)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$121.apply(Defaults.scala:1519)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$121.apply(Defaults.scala:1517)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1522)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1516)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1539)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1466)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1418)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;3.0.0: not found

Cannot start with errors.
```

I also tried already the described way of File-->invalid caches/restart but also did not help

Comment: Where is the `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.6.12"` library dependency? Or, which play-version are you using?

Comment: I am using Play 2.5

Comment: have you followed these instructions https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean ?

Comment: Yes i followed but unfortenatly the Error still occurs unless i put    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean) in build.sbt but then i get a new Error while importing SBT project:<br/>
build.sbt:5: error: not found: value PlayEbean
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
                                                               ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
Invalid response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is with the scala version of the sbt.
sbt 0.13 works with scala 2.10, and sbt 1.0 works with scala 2.12

all plugins that you use must be in the same scala version as the sbt

from this line:

> com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-play-ebean:3.0.0 (scalaVersion=**2.11**, sbtVersion=**0.13**)

I understand that you are using sbt 0.13.x, but somewhere set the scala version to 2.11.x

(maybe in `project/build.sbt` or `project/plugins.sbt`)
you shouldn't set the scala version in those files

---

to clarify, I'm not talking about the

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
```

that you have in your build.sbt, it is fine.
I'm talking about the scala version of the sbt process it's self

Comment: just to add the file you need to modify is the build.properties in the project directory and more specifically the `sbt.version` property... thank @lev your answer solve my issue